# Can I use rrdtool for on /off measurement

Tags: rrdtool

I'm new to rrdtool and I'd like to know if it fits my needs.
I have a script that measures if a sensor is on or off. This script can output yes/no on/off  0/1  or whatever.
I'd like to record this in a database and be able to answer the questions below:

- At what time the sensor switched on for the first time today
- When did it switch on for the last time today
- How long was it on today, assuming that the sensor was on if it was on during 2 measurements
- How long was it on this week, month and year
- Was it on or of at a specific time  last year

Is rrdtool meant for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rrdtool is not a classical database. Instead of storing discrete events, it samples its input. This means that you can easily answer all the quantitative questions but not the questions about certain events.

Setup a database with `DS:xxx:GAUGE...` and run `rrdtool update file.rrd timestamp:state` whenever the state of your sensor changes. (Make sure to run one update every mrhb interval, so that rrdtool does not think you have died.

You can now ask rrdtool for the average value of xxx and this will be express for how much of the time interval the sensor has been on.